# How to go about storing position order in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I created a ToDo app with a draggable list and I'm wondering how to store the order and tie it to the user. My first instinct was to create an object with the order number and the data it is paired with, then store it as a string, and update according to that. I learned I shouldn't do it this way and do it the relational way. How should I go about structuring it when you can add more to the order, there's multiple lists that also can be rearranged, and it's tied to a user?

Comment: I think you need to research and study database design. Just learning about database normalization can give you a big boost in the design.